# Error en update postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hola estoy intentando realizar un update mediante una query que pase desde sqlserver a postgresql. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
UPDATE "USUARIOS" SET "USER_FCH_ULTIMO_INGRESO"= CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, '2020-01-08 19:05:00', 20), "USER_FCH_PROX_INGRESO"= CONVERT(TIMESTAMP, '2020-02-08 19:05:00', 20), "USER_ESTADO"= '1', "USER_PAGO"= '10000.000' WHERE "USER_ID" IN ('25232')
```

Me da un error de sintaxis en el cual timestamp esta erroneo

Comment: que es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Recuerda incluir en tus preguntas el mensaje de error completo

Answer (score 1):

El error se da porque usa la funcion CONVERT que es de Microsoft SqlServer, pero no existe en PostgreSQL . Debería utilizar el casteo standard de SQL

CAST ('2020-01-08 19:05:00' AS TIMESTAMP)